# Use of undeclared type "Firebase"

Tags: ios, firebase

I installed cocoapods using "sudo gem install cocoapods" and followed the very basic instructions from Firebase along with many tutorials to install the frameworks, yet I keep getting this error when I try to create my first reference. The file lets me import Firebase without error, it lets me use FIRApp.configure() without error, but when I want to make a Firebase reference I can't do it. Any help would be much appreciated, thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are the new [Firebase Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/start). Firebase is now split into multiple libraries, so now the correct way to create a reference is:

```
var myRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
```

This is a reference to the root of your database. You might have to import FirebaseDatabase, but this should work.

Comment: Thank you so much, you have no idea how long I spent trying to figure that out

Comment: No problem! Just remember to check this question off as answered. Most of the other Firebase stuff is the same, but the class names have changed a bit.

Answer (score -3):

To solve your problem, use an `import` statement this way after pod installation:

```
#import <FirebaseAuth/FirebaseAuth.h>
```

Add this in `appdelegate.h` and wherever you are using view controller.